# Determine the big Theta expression for this fragment

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Determine Θ for the following code fragment in the average case. Assume that all variables are of type "int". Assume array A contains a random permutation of the values from 0 to n−1. This is the code fragment:

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (j = 0; A[j] != i; j++)
    sum++;
}
```

I found that the answer is Θ(n^2) in the average case, but I couldn't understand why.

I am trying to figure out how to find the expected number of times the inner loop will run on average, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: The body of the inner loop will always be executed `n * (n+1) / 2` times because  `A` is a permutation of `0 .. n-1`. Thus, for every iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will run from `0` to one of `0 .. n-1` (ie until the current `i` from the outer loop is found)

Comment: The inner loop scans the arrray until it finds an item `A[j]` equal to a given `i`. And `i` assumes all integer values from `0` through `n-1` due to the outer loop. So the inner loop will perform `n` scans of all possible lengths: 1, 2, ...n (in an order depending on the contents of `A[]`). As a result, the `sum++` is executed `1+2+...+n` number of times. The compact expression for this sum is given by @noname in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way: if we have a normal distribution over range `[0, n-1]`, for `n` random variables of A, we expect to see each variable exactly once. That means, A is expected to be some sort of a permutation of `{1, 2, ..., n-1}` give or take.
The second for-loop continues running until it has found an element of A with value `i`. Since the expected position of this element is `n/2`, the second for-loop runs for expected `n/2` number of times. Multiply that by the first for-loop running for `n` number of times, and the expected running time would be Θ(n^2). You can alternatively assume that you would equally visit some elements sooner (say after `1` or `2` iterations), and some later (say after `n-2` or `n-1` iterations), so overall you'd need
`1 + 2 + ... + n-1` number of operations, which results in Θ(n^2) running time.